# Custom jersey class member injection exception

Tags: java, jersey

i have created a custom injectable provider, i've tried 2 approaches:

1)

```
@Provider
public static final class PrincipleInjectableProvider extends PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider<Context, Principal>
{
    public PrincipleInjectableProvider()
    {
        super(Principal.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Injectable<Principal> getInjectable(final ComponentContext ic, final Context a)
    {
        return new AbstractHttpContextInjectable<Principal>() {

            @Override
            public Principal getValue(final HttpContext c)
            {
                return c.getRequest().getUserPrincipal();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

2)

```
@Provider
public static final class PrincipleInjectableProvider extends AbstractHttpContextInjectable<Principal>
    implements InjectableProvider<Context, Type>, Injectable<Principal>
{

    @Override
    public ComponentScope getScope()
    {
        return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public Injectable<Principal> getInjectable(final ComponentContext ic, final Context a, final Type c)
    {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getValue(final HttpContext c)
    {
        return c.getRequest().getUserPrincipal();
    }
}
```

i made sure to add this class to my resource config:

```
final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new DefaultResourceConfig(PrincipleInjectableProvider.class);
```

and in my REST resource i try to inject the class like this:

```
@Context
private Principal _principal;
```

I was originally planning on using a separate annotation called @Principal, but i would settle right now on making this work.

When i was trying to inject this as a method param, it was successful (with some changes to the injectable class, to implement

```
InjectableProvider<Context, Parameter>
```

instead)

but i just can't seem to inject it as a class member..

This is the exception message i'm getting:

```
Missing dependency for field: private com.....principal.Principal com.....net.TestResource._principal
```

I went through all the other posts that are relevant, but couldn't find a solution there. Most were fixed by changing from

```
InjectableProvider<Context, Parameter>
```

to

```
InjectableProvider<Context, Type>
```

Please help me find what I've done wrong here,
I tried with jersey 1.12 and 1.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i found out my problem was that our resources are singletons, so these per-request injectable providers can't work.
Instead i implemented a signleton injectable provider that works similarly to how @Context works, with proxies and thread local.